# Select data from SQL Server and copy into .csv file using python

Tags: export-to-csv, return-value

I have used this code:

```
conn = pymssql.connect(
    host=r'192.*.*.*',
    user=r'sever\Administrator',
    password=r'***',
   database='Leaf')

mycursor = conn.cursor()
def close():
            window.destroy()

label_title = Label(window, text ="Enter Customer Code", font ="TimesRoman 20").grid(row= 0, column= 1)
label1 = Label(window, text ="Customer Code", font ="TimesRoman 13").grid(row= 10, column =0, padx=10, sticky ="w")
customer_box = Entry(window, width=50).grid(row = 10, column =1)
def download():
                sql_query = "select distinct customer_code,customer_name,channel_description,category,brand,brandform,subbrandform_name,sum(retailing) as sales,Month(Document_Date) as Month,Year(Document_Date) as Year from <tablename> where document_date between '2022-6-1' and '2022-6-30' and Customer_code IN('*values') group by customer_code,customer_name,channel_description,category,brand,brandform,subbrandform_name,Month(Document_Date),Year(Document_Date)"
                values =(customer_box)
                mycursor.execute(sql_query, values)
                result = mycursor.fetchall()
                df = pd.DataFrame(result)
                #print(result)
                df.to_csv (r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Output\CustomerWiseData.csv', index = False) # place 'r' before the path name
                
but1 = Button(window, text ="Download", font ="TimesRoman 13", command=download).grid(row = 15, column=0, padx=10, pady =20, ipadx=20)
but1 = Button(window, text ="Exit", font ="TimesRoman 13", command =close).grid(row = 15, column=1, padx=10, pady=20, ipadx=20)

mainloop( )
```

Planning to get value passed from the text box, it's not throwing any error but not getting an answer, only empty CSV file was created but data is not available.

Please help me find an answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a pythonist myself but I think the problem might be that you're adding a non-string type when calling `mycursor.execute(sql_query, values)` I'm not very sure but maybe `values` is not a string, it may be just the widget. According to [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_entry.htm) guide to get a string from an entry component you must use the method `get()`. You should check [python's mysql connector's documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html)

So, in a nutshell maybe changing `values =(customer_box)` to `values = (customer_box.get())` would solve the issue (all of this is just assuming that you're using tkinter)

And also make sure your SQL operation is correct.

Good luck!